# Auto scroll ScrollView when I touch on the bottom of the screen

Tags: node.js, react-native, scrollview

I trying to create a view which have a scroll view. If I Touch to bottom or if I drag my  finger to bottom ,then the Scrollview should scroll automatically in fixed speed. consider the below Image
[image]

I am using `PanResponder` class in react native to achieve this functionalities.
for scrolling I am using `scrollTo()` . But I am failed do this. I like to share my code but it was too bulky and not understandable.

So my question is Is anyone have any code to achieve this. or Is there any libraries available?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollToEnd({animated: true})` to go the bottom of scrollView in react-native.

From doc.s of facebook https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrolltoend

```
scrollToEnd()
```

If this is a vertical ScrollView scrolls to the bottom. If this is a horizontal ScrollView scrolls to the right.

Use `scrollToEnd({animated: true})` for smooth animated scrolling, `scrollToEnd({animated: false})` for immediate scrolling. If no options are passed, animated defaults to true.

Comment: scrollToEnd() will scroll to the end of scrollview. but I dont want to goto the end. I just only want a scroll. thats why I am using scrollTo. do you know any library like ths?